# get the full path of file in treeview

Tags: c#, treeview

I have this code to create nodes from directory in treeview

```
if (file.Exists)
{
    var nodes = node.Nodes.Add(file.Name);
    nodes.ImageIndex = nodes.SelectedImageIndex = 2;
    nodes.Tag = file.FullName;
}
```

I need also to get the full path of the file to use it in another form.
AND I APPRECIATE ALL YOUR CREATIVE HELP

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
string myFilePath = Path.GetFullPath(file.Name);

//OR

var fileInfo= new FileInfo(file.Name);
fileInfo.DirectoryName;
```